# Why are the composition factors of Sym(4) and Sym(5) unique?

Tags: finite-groups

I have worked out the CS and CF, and I have been given in my notes that they are unique, but no explanation as to why and in a past paper I am asked for reasoning. Is it because Alt(4) and Alt(5) are the options for maximal groups of Sym 4 and Sym 5 respectively, whereas if the problem were about $D_{30}$ there are other possible CS's?

Thanks

Comment: Wait a minute, Alt(5) *is* simple.

Comment: of course it is. okay then i have no idea the reason behind it.

Comment: never heard of chief factors.

Comment: so what is the reasoning behind it? i can't figure it out

Comment: because i have to give a reason for it in a past paper

Answer (score 1):

The [Jordan–Hölder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series#Uniqueness:_Jordan.E2.80.93H.C3.B6lder_theorem) shows that the composition factors of a finite group are always unique, at least up to isomorphism and reordering. This is similar to the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) which states that the prime factors of an integer are unique, at least up to sign and order.

The subgroups that occur in a composition series of a finite group are called [subnormal subgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_subgroup) and are just the normal subgroups of the normal subgroups of the normal subgroups of the ….

### Sym5

The finite group $\operatorname{Sym}(5)$ has very few normal subgroups: $1$, $\operatorname{Alt}(5)$, and $\operatorname{Sym}(5)$. Notice the normal subgroups of these normal subgroups are again just $1$, $\operatorname{Alt}(5)$, and $\operatorname{Sym}(5)$.

The list of all composition series is just the list of all unrefinable chains of subnormal subgroups. Clearly this group only has the one: $1 \lhd \operatorname{Alt}(5) \lhd \operatorname{Sym}(5)$. In this case the composition series is unique, so the composition factors are unique, not just up to isomorphism and reordering, but really and truly unique.

### Sym4

The finite group $\operatorname{Sym}(4)$ has few normal subgroups: $1$, $K_4$, $\operatorname{Alt}(4)$, and $\operatorname{Sym}(4)$. However, $K_4$ has three more normal subgroups, $\langle(1,2)(3,4)\rangle$, $\langle(1,3)(2,4)\rangle$, and $\langle(1,4)(2,3)\rangle$. There are no more subnormal subgroups. This gives us three composition series:
$$\begin{array}{c}
1 \lhd \langle(1,2)(3,4)\rangle \lhd K_4 \lhd \operatorname{Alt}(4) \lhd \operatorname{Sym}(4) \\
1 \lhd \langle(1,3)(2,4)\rangle \lhd K_4 \lhd \operatorname{Alt}(4) \lhd \operatorname{Sym}(4) \\
1 \lhd \langle(1,4)(2,3)\rangle \lhd K_4 \lhd \operatorname{Alt}(4) \lhd \operatorname{Sym}(4) \\
\end{array}$$
Hence we get three sequences of composition factors, so they are no longer unique. However, $ \langle(1,2)(3,4)\rangle/1 \cong \langle(1,3)(2,4)\rangle/1$ etc. the composition factors are unique up to isomorphism! No reordering required.

### Dih30

The dihedral group of order 30 has normal subgroups $1$, $C_3$, $C_5$, $C_{15}$, and $D_{30}$. Their normal subgroups are nothing new, so this is the complete list of subnormal subgroups. The complete list of composition series is thus
$$\begin{array}{c}
1 \lhd C_3 \lhd C_{15} \lhd D_{30} \\
1 \lhd C_5 \lhd C_{15} \lhd D_{30}
\end{array}$$
so the composition factors are not unique, but even worse they are not isomorphic: $C_3 /1 \not\cong C_5/1$. However, with just a little bit of reordering everything is fine: $C_3/1 \cong C_{15}/C_5$ and $C_{15}/C_3 \cong C_5/1$. Hence the composition factors are unique up to isomorphism and reordering.

This is the typical case. Sym4 and Sym5 are just weird.